# Pull dynamic string out of embedded RESX

Tags: silverlight, resx

I have a RESX resource file that I can retrieve the values out of using the strongly typed properties and assign to values in my Silverlight 3 app. However at runtime I need to generate the lookup key based on some values to avoid a ton of if/switch statements. I'm trying to use the ResourceManager, but it doesn't like .resx files.

Searched far and wide... is this just not possible in SL3? Does anyone have another suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you just use reflection on the strongly typed property class created by the resx generator?

Comment: There is a type, probably in a subnamespace Properties, that corresponds to your RESX file. It uses Resource Manager under the covers. To dynamically grab items you don't know the name of at build time, use reflection: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy(VS.95).aspx

Comment: Sorry... I get Reflection :) I hadn't seen that approach and was a bit surprised this is a possible work around... just didn't seem like it would be that complex. I'll fall back to this. Thanks Jeff.